# PHP Parse HTML code

Tags: php, html, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

How can I parse HTML code held in a PHP variable if it something like:

```
<h1>T1</h1>Lorem ipsum.<h1>T2</h1>The quick red fox...<h1>T3</h1>... jumps over the lazy brown FROG!
```

I want to **only get the text that's between the headings** and I understand that it's not a good idea to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: @everyone who closed this is duplicate. This is different because OP does not want text `T1, T2, T3` but the text after one heading ends and before next heading begins. e.g. `Lorem ipsum.`. So, *this* is different. Please take a look.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use PHP [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
<?php
   $str = '<h1>T1</h1>Lorem ipsum.<h1>T2</h1>The quick red fox...<h1>T3</h1>... jumps over the lazy brown FROG';
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);

   //get all H1
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

   //display all H1 text
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
?>
```

This outputs as:

```
 T1
 T2
 T3
```

---

**[EDIT]: After OP Clarification:**

If you want the content like *Lorem ipsum.* etc, you can directly use this regex:

```
<?php
   $str = '<h1>T1</h1>Lorem ipsum.<h1>T2</h1>The quick red fox...<h1>T3</h1>... jumps over the lazy brown FROG';
   echo preg_replace("#<h1.*?>.*?</h1>#", "", $str);
?>
```

this outputs:

> Lorem ipsum.The quick red fox...... jumps over the lazy brown FROG

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get the text between <h1></h1> as in:
"Lorem ipsum.", "The quick red fox..." etc. So not the text between H1 tags, but rather the text between an ending </h1> tag and a starting <h1>.

Comment: That's closer, thank you.

I'll try to be more clear: I want to get the text between headings, count its length and decide if I want to hide part of it.

You're answer is very helpful though. But what I want to do is keep all the text, just add a bit of html to hide part of it.

Comment: This is a great tip @shamittomar! Thanks for that! One suggestion, maybe a foreach instead of a for loop would be a smidgen cleaner, but this really helped me out.