# how to parse contents from a html file using CURL?

Tags: php, html, curl, html-parsing, web-scraping

I want to parse an XHTML content using CURL. How to scrap **transaction number, weight, height, Width** between `<table>` tags. How to scrap **only the contents from this HTML document and get it as array** using CURL?

```
transactions.php

 <table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
       <tr> 
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="30%" class="Mellemrubrikker">Transaction Number::</td>
        <td width="70%">24752734576547IN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="30%" class="Mellemrubrikker">Weight:</td>
        <td width="70%">0.85 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="30%" class="Mellemrubrikker">Length:</td>
        <td width="70%">543 mm.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="30%" class="Mellemrubrikker">Height:</td>
        <td width="70%">156 mm.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="30%" class="Mellemrubrikker">Width:</td>
        <td width="70%">61 mm.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
         <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>    
    </table>
```

index.php

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/htmlparse/transactions.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($output);
echo $output;
?>
```

This code gets whole html content from **transactions.php** . How to get data between `<table>` as an array value ?

Comment: this is not a do my work for me site.  what have you tried, and what didn't work as you expected?

Comment: yes i try using a curl,but i am not familiar with preg_match.

Comment: Regarding parsing HTML using regexes, see ["RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Comment: @ Andrew Barber: hi, I've added the curl code that I used to parse html. It retrieves whole contentwith tags from the file. I want to get data only. How can retrieve it as array result ?

Answer (score 3):

Try simple html dom from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

If you don't mind to use python or perl you can use beautifulsoup or WWW-Mechanize

Comment: came here to suggest the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Document Object Model rather than writing your own parsing code or (God forbid!) regular expressions.

Here's an example in PHP:  [PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code/3627553#3627553)