# Cake PHP: how can i pass dynamic arguments to ajax->link?

Tags: cakephp

I have an $ajax->link that calls a controller action; it needs additional parameters contained in a hidden field, say

```
<div id=my_id>
```

How can i pass the value of my_id to the $ajax->link?

Comment: <?php echo $ajax->link('link1',array('controller'=>'tests' ,'action'=>'simple_ajax1_fcn',$my_id), array('update' => 'divout')                                                );
?>

Comment: my_id is the DOM id, if i call $my_id i get a server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) - its a bit tricky but it does what you want:

[PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)

On the other hand - if you know a bit of JavaScript - you can do away with using the Ajax helper and write the link yourself.