# Parsing a Source With REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I want to get all Performance ID's from [this page](http://www124.popmundo.com/Common/Performances.asp?action=ComingPerformances&ArtistID=1962457) .

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://www124.popmundo.com/Common/Performances.asp?action=ComingPerformances&ArtistID=1962457");

$regex = "Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)";
//$regex = "/Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)/";
//$regex = "/Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)/s";

//all pattern variations tested, not working

if(preg_match_all($regex, $content, $m))
    print_r($m);
else
    echo "FALSE";

// this is returning FALSE
```

Comment: You might check out [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use regex? If your code contains large hard to read regexes in string literals it may be more difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: @Ziggy, this is my code : http://pastebin.com/GrBx4CEm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `&amp;` in your regex.

Comment: and here I just built my own and was gonna suggest `"Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&PerformanceID=([0-9]{8})"` :p

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $regex = "/Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)/";
```

Comment: It still works: http://www.ideone.com/R2nmd. The problem is most likely that `file_get_contents` (can't test it on ideone) doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, i'm testing on http://www.regexpal.com/ . If i testing on directly `<td>` tags . But if i copy paste all source codes of page, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an escape problem. Not knowing php, I would guess one of these
might fix it:

$regex = `'Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)';`

or

$regex = `"Performances\\.asp\\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)";`

or

$regex = `'/Performances\.asp\?action=Arrangements&amp;PerformanceID=([0-9]+)/';`

Comment: no we solve problem. It's because of using `&amp;` instead of `&`.