# PHP/HTML Result Uploader

Tags: php, html, mysql

I run a program which produces either a HTML or PDF file with results from races.

Unfortunately this is a fixed format and can't be changed. The results can vary massively so I don't think I will be able to put the directly into a database as the number of cars/classes/types of races is broad.

This is an example of one of the results. Example File Name: Heat 1 - Round 3.pdf/html

```
Meeting Name - 07/10/2018
Heat 1 - Round 3

Race Class Name

Pos   Car#   Name          Result       Average   Best
1     2      Driver Name   27/304.22    11.22     10.67
2     4      Driver Name2  26/355.12    11.28     10.57
etc...
```

They are stored locally on the race timing computer in a directory called Web.

I want to be able to automatically upload these when they are created to my site in some way. From here I want to display them according to the date of the meeting/month.

Here is an example of what I want it to be like: [Here](http://nwrcr.co.uk/Account/Results.aspx)

For uploading them, I want some sort of program (I guess it will have to be c# or something similar) to input the date of the meeting, meeting name, folder to watch then watch that folder for new files which get put into it by the program. From there they are uploaded in with the inputs from the program.

I know this is a basic overview, I am just looking for a general nudge in the right direction of the solution.

I only really know PHP, HTML, MySQL as a base.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This will need more information to answer it properly. You mentioned data is stored in the directory? Can you enlighten us on directory structure you get in your local system, how those data looks like in filename and do files follow some kind of naming convention?

Comment: The program dumps the file into a directory called Web. The files are named according to their race eg. 
Heat 3 in Round 1 will be called 'Heat 3 - Round 1.htm'.
The finals are named by car class then the final that it is eg. 'Touring Cars - A Final.htm' 'Touring Cars' is the class name and 'A Final is the quickest final. The next lowest would be B Final. Hope this will help?

Comment: And in this case, I guess HTML parsing using Node/PHP will be perfect, given that the html files are used and are generated with table related tags. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449116/html-table-to-php-array to give you an idea

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.