# how would I screen scrape a page like this using file_get_contents and preg_match?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, preg-match, file-get-contents

I have a page with many HTML lines like this:

```
<ul><li><a href='a_silly_link_that_changes_each_line.php'>the_content_i_need</a></li></ul>
```

Now as you can see, theres a link in that line, which unfortunately changes on each line.

So I need a way to scrape the content in that line, without letting the link get in the way.

I've also tried to scrape like this: `.php'>(*.)</a></li></ul>` but thats no good, as it returns allot of unwanted content.

Also, because there are many lines on the page that i need to take the content from, could i just `loop` through, somehow?

I'm using `preg_match` and `file_get_contents` but am open to other suggestions. :)

Comment: So each link you want is in a <li> element in a <ul> element? Does each <li> have its own <ul>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)

Use something like:

```
   $str = '<ul><li><a src="test.html">linky</a></li></ul>';
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('ul');
    for($i =0;$i<$items->length;$i++){
        $ul = $items->item($i);
        $li=$ul->firstChild;
        if($li->nodeName=='li' && $li->firstChild->nodeName=='a'){
            //do something with $li->firstChild->nodeValue 

        }
    }
```

In this case, `$li->firstChild->nodeValue` will be `linky`.

That should do it :)

Comment: Thanks for using proper attribution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```php
$match = array();
preg_match_all( '~\\.php>(.*?)</a></li></ul>~', file_get_contents( $filename), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)`.
```

This will match all links inside your file. `*?` means "match 0-inf characters but as little characters as possible" (greedy killer) so you won't be getting any unvanted content.

Comment: PREG_SET_ORDER is causing: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference