# How do to get specific data from a webpage using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I was trying to get data from a webpage using PHP and file_get_contents along with regular expressions, but I can't seem to get the correct data from the page.

Here is my code,

```
<?php
   $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com');
   preg_match_all('/<p><b>(.*)<\ /b><br>(.*)<br>(.*)<\ /p>/ms', $homepage, $matches);
   $def = $matches[0];
   echo $def;
   ?>
```

My regular expressions aren't picking up anything even though there is html code that matches the expressions. As a test I also tried replacing the first preg_match function with the following one.

```
preg_match_all('/<div>(.*)<\ /div>/ms', $homepage, $matches);
```

This only picked up 2 of the many div tags on the page. What is wrong with my code and what is the correct way it should be written?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using RegEx you could simply use PHP's [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com');
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($homepage);
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('div');
$def = $items->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

(referenced form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code) question).