# regex matching correct text

Tags: php, regex

I am having problems trying to extract the correct value from a text

I want to extract `14.50` from the following text (which is the last decimal number in the string).

**string**

```
<span class="ob-pricedetails">Price:</span> &#036;57.71<span style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px;">(&#163;37.61)</span><br/><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #000000;">Shipping (UK):</span>&#036;14.50
```

I have been trying to use the following regex

**regex**

```
(?<=Shipping \(UK\):<\/span>&#163;|&#036;)(.*)
```

which returns the following result for some strange reason

```
57.71<span style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px;">(&#163;37.61)</span><br/><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #000000;">Shipping (UK):</span>&#036;14.50
```

What am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just use javascript to extract values from the DOM?

Comment: Greediness. Use `.*?` or the `/U` flag. Better yet make the match more specific.

Comment: @Blaine because i am scraping a website...

Comment: Oh look mk_89 is attempting to parse HTML using regex - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - not a good idea... Better to use a parser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) for this.

Comment: @Buggabill this looks interesting, I'll have a look at it

Comment: If you are scraping a site, it is all the more reason to do so... You are asking for trouble if they change things.

Comment: @Buggabill yeh I know what you mean it can get messy, I just had no idea that there was a simpler way

Comment: You should convert the string to HTML and then use the DOM parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
preg_match('/Shipping \(UK\):<\/span>&#036;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $html, $matches);
```

Of course you should listen to everyone suggesting yo use a DOM parser instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.

```
[0-9\.]+$
```