# Extracting td/tr from html in bash?

Tags: html, bash, web-scraping, html-table

I got the page http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php and I want to extract given CPU's with their Name, Rank and benchmark score.

Example ("Intel Core i5"):

```
Intel Core i5-3450 @ 3.10GHz - Score: 3333 - Rank: 1
Intel Core i5-3450S @ 2.80GHz - Score: 2222 - Rank: 2
Intel Core i5-2380P @ 3.10GHz - Score: 1111 - Rank: 3
...
```

How can I do that in bash? Tried to start with something like that (without cpu filtering - don't know how that works):

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php | grep '^<TR><TD>' \
| sed \
    -e 's:<TR>::g'  \
    -e 's:</TR>::g' \
    -e 's:</TD>::g' \
    -e 's:<TD>: :g' \
| cut -c2- >> /home/test.txt
```

Output is something like that:

```
<A HREF="cpu_lookup.php?cpu=686+Gen&amp;id=1495">686 Gen</A> 288 1559 NA NA
<A HREF="cpu_lookup.php?cpu=AMD+A10-4600M+APU&amp;id=10">AMD A10-4600M APU</A> 3175 388 NA NA
<A HREF="cpu_lookup.php?cpu=AMD+A10-4655M+APU&amp;id=11">AMD A10-4655M APU</A> 3017 406 NA NA
```

Comment: How do you want the output to look?

Comment: That example is more like your current output looks

Comment: `Bash` definitely ain't a good tool to parse `HTML`. You sure you can't use something else? (`python` or `perl` advised by i put on my robe an wizard hat)

Comment: I mean you can manually sed/cut/tr/... through that but this would basically mean reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @BeniBela see "Example ("Intel Core i5")" <- That's how it should look.

Comment: @davak python/perl is not installed - so no. Well php is available.

Comment: If php is an option for you, you might wanna look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Comment: Looks like another instance where this is a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1106534

Comment: That answers today are really helpful... Thanks.

Comment: Those were comments, not answers...

Comment: "just use perl or php" is actually an answer ;)

Comment: Use [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to download an additional program you can use my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

All CPUs:

```
xidel http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php -e '//table[@id="cputable"]//tr/concat(td[1], " - Score: ", td[2], " - Rank: ", td[3])'
```

Those starting with Intel...:

```
xidel http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php -e '//table[@id="cputable"]//tr[starts-with(td[1], "Intel Core i5")]/concat(td[1], " - Score: ", td[2], " - Rank: ", td[3])'
```

It can even sort them for rank (never used that feature before):

```
xidel http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php -e 'for $row in //table[@id="cputable"]//tr[starts-with(td[1], "Intel Core i5")] order by $row/td[3] return $row/concat(td[1], " - Score: ", td[2], " - Rank: ", td[3])' --extract-kind=xquery
```

Comment: That's amazing. Never heard about Xidel.
Thanks for that nice solution. Works as expected.

Comment: Well, I had it sitting as fifth-complete library on my harddisk for almost four years, before I told anyone about it...

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution tailored strictly to the current format of the page:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function nextcell
{
    cell=${line%%</TD>*}
    # remove closing link tag if any
    cell=${cell%</?>}
    cell=${cell##*>}
    line=${line#*</TD>}
}

while read line
do
    if [[ ! "$line" =~ cpu_lookup.php ]]
    then
        continue
    fi
    nextcell
    echo -n "$cell"
    nextcell
    echo -n " - Score: $cell"
    nextcell
    echo " - Rank: $cell"
done
```