# How to parse this kind of HTML code with using PHP?

Tags: php, html-parsing

First of all, I found some threads here on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code), but it's not exactly what I am looking for.

Here is a sample of text that I have:

`Some text bla bla bla bla<br /><b>Date</b>: 2012-12-13<br /><br /><b>Name</b>: Peter Novak<br /><b>Hobby</b>: books,cinema,facebook`

The desired output:

```
2012-12-13
Peter Novak
books,cinema,facebook
```

I need to save this information into our database, but I don't know, how to detect between the `<b>` tags the value (eg. `Date`) and then immediately the value (in this case `: 2012-12-13`)...

I would be grateful for every help with this, thank you!

Comment: It's going to be messy because the html isn't semantic. Is there any other way of retrieving the information? Xml?

Comment: is there are parent element surrounding the HTML you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's not much DOM to traverse, there's not much a DOM traversal tool can do with this.

This should work:

1) Remove everything before the `b` tag.

2) Remove the `b` tags. A DOM traversal tool can do this, but if they are pure text, even a regex can do it, and it can remove the colon and the subsequent whitespace in the same pass: `<b\s*>[^<]+</b\s*>:\s*`

3) Change sequences of  `br` tags to bare newlines (do you really want to?). The DOM traversal tool can do this, but so can regexes: `(?:<br\s*/?>)+`

```
$html = preg_replace('#^[^<]+#', "", $html);
$html = preg_replace('#<b\s*>[^<]+</b\s*>:\s*#', "", $html);
$html = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>)+#', "\n", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<b>Date</b>`, `<b>Name</b>`, `<b>Hobby</b>` and the `<br />`'s will always be there in that way, I suggest you use [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

For instance, to get the date:

```
// Get start position, +13 because of "<b>Date</b>: "
$dateStartPos = strpos($yourText, "<b>Date</b>") + 13;
// Get end position, use dateStartPos as offset
$dateEndPos = strpos($yourText, "<br />", $dateStartPos);
// Cut out the date, the length is the end position minus the start position
$date = substr($yourText, $dateStartPos, ($dateEndPos - $dateStartPos));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format is consistent, then [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can work for you:

```
<?php
$text = "Some text bla bla bla bla<br /><b>Date</b>: 2012-12-13<br /><br /><b>Name</b>: Peter Novak<br /><b>Hobby</b>: books,cinema,facebook";
$tokenized = explode(': ', $text);
$tokenized[1] = explode("<br", $tokenized[1]);
$tokenized[2] = explode("<br", $tokenized[2]);
$tokenized[3] = explode("<br", $tokenized[3]);

$date = $tokenized[1][0];
$name = $tokenized[2][0];
$hobby = $tokenized[3][0];

echo $date;
echo $name;
echo $hobby;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) you can achieve this easily (just like jQuery)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('Some text bla bla bla bla<br /><b>Date</b>: 2012-12-13<br /><br /><b>Name</b>: Peter Novak<br /><b>Hobby</b>: books,cinema,facebook');
```

Or

```
$html = file_get_html('http://your_page.com/');
```

then

```
foreach($html->find('text') as $t){
    if(substr($t, 0, 1)==':')
    {
        // do whatever you want
        echo substr($t, 1).'<br />';
    }
}
```

**The output of the example is given below**

```
2012-12-13
Peter Novak
books,cinema,facebook
```