# How can i define a PHP variable by the content of an HTML tag?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, echo

HTML

```
<p id="a" name="a"></p>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=price;
```

If price is a variable how do I make a php variable that is = to the result that is placed in the HTML of id "a" i?

```
$price = $_POST['a'];
```

when echoed this variable comes up blank, and yes I do have a form set up that is handled by a PHP page.

Comment: You asked an extremely similar question 25 minutes ago, and I told you what you would need to do: [Your Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155008/i-need-to-echo-results-that-are-rendered-inside-a-span-tag)

Answer (score 3):

That's not how forms work.

The browser will only send values of **form controls** (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`) to the server.
It won't send values of arbitrary named elements.  (in fact, that `name="a"` is invalid HTML)

Instead, you should use an `<input type="hidden" name="a" value="" />`, and set the `value` attribute of this `<input>` tag to the value you want PHP to get.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want only to change the values in HTML elements. For that you need a XML parser ([i.d](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)). I think [shamittimar's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627553/1493365) may help you. He does exactly what you want.