# Fetching content from external website

Tags: php, jquery, file-get-contents

Let's say I want to extract the current bitcoin exchange rate (in EUR) from the German exchange [bitcoin.de](http://www.bitcoin.de) and the value shall be fetched each time I visit my site (so no caching). I was able to extract the value in PHP:

```php
// fetch contents from bitcoin.de
$url = 'https://www.bitcoin.de/de/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

// cut everything before specified text
$content = strstr($content, "Aktueller Bitcoin Kurs");

// extract rate
$rate = strstr($content, "<b>");
$rate = substr($rate, 3);
$rate = strstr($rate, "€", true);

echo $rate . " EUR"; // e.g. 105,51 EUR
```

This works fine and prints the correct current value as it can be found on the bitcoin.de website. But I am fetching the whole website content, substract everything I don't need, and return it.

My question: Is there a way (maybe also using jQuery) to solve this more efficiently; ergo not fetching the whole site code but only the rate value?

Comment: are they provide API?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Id you want to do it realtime it is hard to using php,jquery .Try to find better API \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many APIs available for accessing that data.  While there are way more complex APIs, the information you are looking for is available at

http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker

Comment: Oh - sorry, I missed the whole EUR thing.

http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCEUR/money/ticker

Comment: Yeah, USD was not really helpful as I would have to use a currency coverter API. But the Mt.Gox EUR API is great! Thanks.

Comment: Great!  I dunno exactly what your needs are (update rate, multiple exchanges, etc), but as i said, there are many APIs available for bitcoin data at both the user and developer level.  Here are some links:

For trade info:
http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/

For tech info:
http://blockexplorer.com/q

Comment: By the way: I acceptec this as answer although it doesn't fulfill my requirement to fetch this value from bitcoin.de. But as this Mt.Gox API is really good to handle and easy to use I chose to use Mt.Gox instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that.  The bitcoincharts api has the data from bitcoin.de available to you.  Unfortunately, bitcoin.de doesn't offer an api (publicly, but it must have one _somewhere_ to interface with bitcoincharts.com).  Another option is to use http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=btcdeEUR.  That will give you the most recent transactions at bitcoin.de in csv format.  You can get the results of all markets as a JSON object (if thats preferable) at http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json

Answer (score 2):

You can use `maxlen` parameter with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). This way you can limit how many characters the function will read. You could also cache the results (store locally) on your server, depending on your needs. In your position I would only cache the results, that will bring most of the performance.

Comment: This sounds promising. I edited my question to make clear that caching is explicitly not wanted.

Comment: I know that this kind of data must be fresh, but even caching for a very small time, can have a big performance boost.

Comment: Okay, I think the rate is updated each 15 or 30 minutes. I suppose caching would already make sense in this case? What would you suggest?

Comment: If you need data specifically from this page even caching every 1s is better than making a request for each user. But as someone pointed out, the best way is to make use of an API.

Comment: It also depends on the number of users.

Comment: What caching would you recommend (e.g. sqlite, file system, ...)? It's only a very small group of people.

Comment: Depends on what you have available. The quickest would be redis, mangodb or any other in memory datastructure. But I don't think that write and read speeds are so important here, so sql or filesystem is just fine. The more important thing here is that you don't make a request for every user.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

And you need to read it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627553/2198378

Comment: In how far would this be more efficient? Wouldn't this also fetch the whole site content and pick out what is needed?

Comment: Every crawl need whole contents as html-string at once. And Parse data from crawled data. At least, you need whole data at once.

Comment: Okay I see, so if there is no API available I will have to fetch the whole site and extract what I need. Thanks for your tip!