# Regular Expression to Extract the content between the tags [img] and [/img]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Trying to come up with a PHP regexp that would extract the content of the first [img]...[/img] tag in a text. Can be img or IMG as well.

Really appreciate any help.

Using my poor regexp, I came by with the following, which doesn`t work:

```
/[img](.+)[/img/]
```

Here is one example of text that should work:
   http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_von_D%C3%A4niken]Erich Von Daniken[/url][/align] [align=center][img]http://www.ceticismoaberto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/erich_von_daniken_7.jpg[/img]

It should return only:
http://www.ceticismoaberto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/erich_von_daniken_7.jpg

I am using a webpage to text the regexp:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php
the Php code I`m using is :

```
$message=$post["message"];
//try to locate the first image on the post text
if (preg_match("!http://[^?#]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui", $message, $matches)) {
    return $matches[0];
}
```

The regexp abovev didn`t work for some cases, like the one I showed before and that's why I'm trying a different approach.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Could you post the complete code you tried?

Comment: Can you show us a demo content ? And what exactly you want to extract from it ?

Comment: are you sure you don't want to parse the HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml looks pretty darn easy that way

Comment: Yes, not html, I`m parsing the reply text of mybb forum software, which uses mycode.

Comment: Here is one example that should work:
   http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_von_D%C3%A4niken]Erich Von Daniken[/url][/align] [align=center][img]http://www.ceticismoaberto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/erich_von_daniken_7.jpg[/img]

It should return only:
http://www.ceticismoaberto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/erich_von_daniken_7.jpg

I am using a webpage to text the regexp:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

My Php code I`m using is :
ext
 if (preg_match("!http://[^?#]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui", $message, $matches)) {
  return $matches[0];
 }

The regexp abovevdidn`t work for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/i
```

[] characters should be escaped with \ because they are used by the regex parser.

Comment: In your title you have posted that you need to parse tags between [img]and[img], not [/img], do you have closing tag [/img]?? I've made changes, try it now.

Comment: Yes, I have a closing tag, I tried the last version, still doesnt work.
Using this site to test:
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Comment: @Emerson and nacholibre You should also escape the forward slash: `/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/i`. I tested it [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/pK0uR1).

Comment: Actually it sometimes brings the  opening and closing tags [img] as well. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must scape all brackets characters, and perhaps you have carriage returns. Try this:

```
\[img\](.|\n)*\[/img\]
```