# How to store text in a span tag into a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I just started learning PHP. I have a string called "address" which contain HTML looks like:

```
<div class="address_row">
  <span class="address1">239 House</span>
  <span class="address2">Street South</span>
</div>
```

I am wondering how to store "239 House" into a variable called "address1"

Comment: You could make use of a form using either `POST` or `GET`, along with variables for different (named) fields and storing them from there. Preferably using `POST`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: $address1 = '239 House'

Comment: I have html in a string variable of php. How to use POST OR GET or $address1 = '239 House'

Comment: can you show code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: You could use regex, or some html parser (better).

Comment: $address = 'contain above html'

how to create variable for each span?

Comment: @nevermind can you please some html parser as I am very beginning stage of php.

Comment: Well you're showing us the front end, php is server side. The real question is @how@ did the address populate the divs and intersect it then.

Comment: @Vector please read my question I said its a string which contains html tags ... inside a php variable.

Comment: @Imran Then you should post more code then, and avoid the confusion ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inspiration from this question: [PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)

You can do this using http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

And here's the sample code;

```
$str = '<div class="address_row">
  <span class="address1">239 House</span>
  <span class="address2">Street South</span>
</div>';

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);

// all span elements
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
$span_list = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    $item = $items->item($i);
    $span_list[$item->getAttribute('class')] = $item->nodeValue;
}
extract($span_list);

echo $address1; // 239 House
echo $address2; // Street South
```

Comment: `echo $address1;` (or 2) would be better :)

Comment: That also, **good point**. `echo $str;` will hit 2 birds with one stone. haha!

Comment: Actually, instead of `echo $str` we can also use a simple html page. No need to php :D

Comment: Oh!?... how would you go about it without PHP? "*intrigued*"

Comment: Prefer to use `query('//*[@class="foo"]')` instead of loop

Comment: Printing '239 House' and 'Street South' without assigning them to variables address1 and address2 (`echo $str`) has the same effect with displaying content of $str in a html file, hasn't it? :)

Comment: @oozel I would say so, theoretically yes. I get what you mean now. That's what I thought earlier, in using `JS` to `print document etc.`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Submit an answer then ;-)

Comment: Seems now, that it's **"Battle of the Answers"**.

Comment: Ok, I posted, but my only interest is to show the best way and not gain the right answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Well said ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Could try so, XPath can help in your project:

```
<?php
$str = '<div class="address_row">
  <span class="address1">239 House</span>
  <span class="address2">Street South</span>
</div>';

$a = new DOMDocument;
$a->loadHTML($str);

$b = new DomXPath($a);//set DOM from XPath

//Get <span class=address1>
$address1 = trim($b->query('//*[@class="address1"]')->item(0)->nodeValue);

//Get <span class=address2>
$address2 = trim($b->query('//*[@class="address2"]')->item(0)->nodeValue);

//show variables
echo 'address2: ', $address1, '<br>';
echo 'address2: ', $address2;
```

Test online in [ideone](http://ideone.com/a5COKa).

Links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#External_links
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

you can also try `new simplexmlelement(XMLString)`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: `+1` I should probably learn this. I never picked on that before, never even heard it. But, it looks good. Anyway beginner-friendly tutorials?

Comment: Yeah, that's easier way. But when we consider addressN, loop is inevitable. Actually, I use loop using this possibility.