# How to get value from span and put it into variable using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

OK , This is my Html code :

```
<span id="d"></span>
```

And this is my Java Script code :

```
<script>document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = (date.format('DD'));</script>
```

Now span have a value , I want to get this value from Span and put it into variable then insert it into Database but i don't know how to get value from span .

Comment: Use Jquery Ajax to get the value from id then save it in

Comment: please use DOM as in this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732563/how-to-store-text-in-a-span-tag-into-a-variable-using-php

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't know how to get value from span .

Just use the same property, you used to set the so called "value" to get it as well.

```
var value = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;
```

After doing the above you'll be able to send it to your backend with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This way you will get value

```
var value = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;
```

Use Jquery Ajax to post the value from id then save it in database

```
$.ajax({
   url : pathofyoursavingphpscript.php
   data : {divVal:value} 
   success:function(data){
      alert('value is saved in database');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the value and add it to a php variable

```
$v = "<script> document.write(document.getElementById('d').innerHTML) </script>";
```