# Trying to remove three or more <br> from the_content

Tags: php, regex

As the title says I'm trying to remove and replace three or more `<br>` from `get_the_content();` in my single.php.

I'm currently using this but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the amount of `<br>` in the document.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/(<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]*){3,}/', '<br /><br />', $content);
$content = strip_tags($content, '<br> <p> <a>');
echo $content;
```

This gives me the output:

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rYRPguEjEl8/UrSWUC_jEOI/AAAAAAAANm4/qVle4zdVfsQ/s1600/Alexa+NYC.jpg" imageanchor="1"></a>

<p>
<br />
<br />You don&#8217;t always have to stick to the same colour scheme 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

I can't seem to get the regex to work correctly.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ConnorPeet   People on SO LOVE to say "don't use regex for HTML!"... but then they don't give a solution because using DOM or simpleXML to solve the above issue is a clusterF and they end up using regex to solve it. Just like the accepted answer to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Comment: @DigitalChris I'm using DOM methods for other stuff but as this is just duplicate tags I was under the impression using regex would be fine. I've seen that regex post so many times :)

Comment: As someone very comfortable in Js and the "real" DOM API, I like DOMDocument. You do have a fair point, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?PHP
$input ="<br/><br/><br/><br/>Hello";
highlight_string($input);
$output = preg_replace('/(<br\s*\/?>\s*){3,}/', '<br/><br/>', $input);
highlight_string($output);
?>
```

Comment: What does highlight_string do? It seems to be outputting text with html tags, which isn't what I want.

Comment: If I remove the highligh_string it works fine though.

Comment: @UzumakiDev I used highlight_string to show output with html tags to show that its replacing `<br/>` tags.