# Get the price of an item on Steam Community Market with PHP and Regex

Tags: php, regex, steam

I'm trying to use PHP to get the Steam Community Market price of an item. I take a url (for example : http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29) and then I download the content with `file_get_contents()`. I tried to use this :

```
function getInnerHTML($string, $tagname, $closetagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$closetagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Using

```
getInnerHTML($str, 'span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"', 'span');
```

An example of what I can have with file_get_contents is this :

```
<span class="market_table_value">
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
        $1.92               </span>
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
        $1.68               </span>
    <br/>
</span>
```

But it returns nothing.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: The fact that you're using `.*>(.*)` in your expression instead of a non-greedy pattern and by forgetting the `s` modifier. It's clear that you need to stop using regex and use a [robust html parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for this task, try using PHP's DOM instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Comment: I tried the PHP's DOM but I can't use it because each item in the list has in the span the title attribute, which is different for each item and the title is the price. So I can't know it.

Comment: @ThomasPatKowalski-Zuckerberg: I'm not sure to follow what you mean. Can you edit your question to add sample input?

Comment: OK I just added a sample HTML code.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you'd want to do this the hard way and regex through HTML when there's a perfectly working call which returns JSON. Although the original answer is correct and answers the OP question directly, this provides a much easier and efficient way of getting the market value of an item.

**GET**:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29

**JSON Response**:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "lowest_price": "1,43&#8364; ",
  "volume": "562",
  "median_price": "1,60&#8364; "
}
```

**Response Definitions** :

`success`: boolean value, true if the call was successful or false if something went wrong *or there are no listing for this item on the Steam market*.

`lowest_price`: string value with currency symbol [pre-/ap]pended depending on the query parameters specified. See below for some additional parameter.

`volume`: integer value returned as a string (?) - the total number of this specific item which has been sold/bought.

`median_price`: string value with currency symbol [pre-/ap]pended. The average price at which the item has been sold. See the [Steam marketplace](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29) item graph for a better understanding on how the median is calculated.

**Query Parameters**:

`appid`: The unique (statically defined) Steam application ID of the game/app, in our case 730 for Counter-Strike: Global Offensive. See Valve's development Wiki for a list of other appid's, though this list will most probably always be out of date as new apps are added to their platform frequently.

`market_hash_name`: The name of the item being queried against with the exterior included, retrieving these names can be found when querying against a users inventory, but that's a whole other API call.

`currency`: An integer value; the currency value and format to return the market values. You'll need to tweak and play around with these numbers as I cannot provide too much detail here. Generally I stick to using USD as a global price and use my own currency API to translate into other currencies.

**This is an undocumented endpoint and therefore might not be permanent, or may be subject to change, nobody knows.**

Comment: Is there a way to get the pricing of multiple items rather than sending one GET request per item for the prices?

Comment: No, but see my answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270881/how-get-a-response-of-multiple-price-items-on-the-market/27641646#27641646

Comment: @snh Hey can u please tell me what i this median price because few items have them and few dont

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little more information.

Comment: @Stevovosaurus, what is the currency value for usd? currency 3 is returning to me euro dollars.

Comment: I believe `1` is USD.

Comment: Currently: 1 = USD; 13 = CAD; 4 = CHF;  7 = R$; 9 = kr;

Comment: You'll run into problems with error 429 if you try to use this for all your inventory items. Because you'll make to many requests too fast.

Comment: @cheesey Caching. Nuff said.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex for this task (see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but there's a more explanatory link somewhere on SO)

You want to use XPath to select your elements based on fine criteria. From [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php) this should get you the nodes you want:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"]');
```

the XPath `//span[@class="..."]` means select all `span` tags within the document the have the expected class attribute.

Comment: @Robin I'm trying something similar to OP. The data I wish to parse http://pastebin.com/1J2syC0n . Is it possible to use XPath on such a string of text. Or do I need to make it into a type of file before I can run the query on it?

Comment: @Ríomhaire: if you have another question, you'll have more support by posting it as such. But before that I suggest you try it out to figure what's working as expected and what's not, in order to clarify your exact issue !

Answer (score 0):

I created a node.js module via npm for the cs:go market. https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo-market It only gets single prices at the moment, but let me know if there is additional functionality you'd like me to add.

Comment: Man this is so cool :o if only I knew anything about nodejs... :c