# What standard is the currency parameter

Tags: get, currency, url-parameters, iso, steam-web-api

When I wanted to get the median price of an item on the steam market I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394279/8700480) answer. It gets the lowest and median price of an item. The one thing I had trouble understanding which currency number corresponds with what currency and if so, which industry standard is used here.

This is an example URL:

`https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20VariCamo%20(Minimal%20Wear)`

In [the documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/inventory/economy/GetAssetPrices) it says it is [`ISO 4217`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes):

> An optional ISO 4217 currency code. If specified, only prices for this currency need to be

But that's clearly not the case.

When I [put in](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20VariCamo%20(Minimal%20Wear)) 1 as the currency parameter, I get dollar.

With 2 [I get](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=2&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20VariCamo%20(Minimal%20Wear)) pounds.

And with 3 it [responds with](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20VariCamo%20(Minimal%20Wear)) euro.

...

The max [seems to be](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=41&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20VariCamo%20(Minimal%20Wear)) 41 with the Uruguayan Peso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All actual currency codes and other respective information about currencies on Steam can be found in *global.js* on https://steamcommunity.com/market/. Just open this page. Then open developer console and search for g_rgCurrencyData variable like on image below.

[Location of g_rgCurrencyData  variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqjFq.png)

Besides codes there are info about formatting for each currency which is useful when you need to parse data from page or automate some actions.