# How to fetch total market value of csgo market

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm working on a site and I'm trying to find an api that returns the total value in $ of every skin in csgo.

What I want to achieve is something like this: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E2-bYmJXEAQmO5u.jpg

How can I do that?

Comment: Saw a discussion on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170185/steam-market-api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @NewbieCody for linking me to the answer.

Example:

```
data = requests.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=name&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=0")
json_data = json.loads(data.text)
print(json_data)
```

Every page returns 100 items so I itinerated over [the number of pages]/100 adding 100 every time to the start parameter and extracted the prices to make the graph.