# Get steam item prices

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

I was wondering if there is any efficient way to get the prices of an item on steam. 
I found  :

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Factory%20New%29

You get JSON with only "lowest_price". How I can get JSON with 3 lowest prices  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the price of an item on Steam Community Market with PHP and Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055673/get-the-price-of-an-item-on-steam-community-market-with-php-and-regex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use

> render?start=0&count=10&currency=3&language=english&format=json

currency: 1 for USD, 2 for GBP, 3 for EUR, 5 for RUB

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AK-47%20%7C%20Blue%20Laminate%20%28Factory%20New%29/render?start=0&count=10&currency=3&language=english&format=json