# Retrieve all CS:GO items via Steam API or endpoint

Tags: json, api, steam, items

I was just wondering, is there anyway to retrieve all CS:GO items some way through the Steam Web API, or a JSON endpoint, or some other alternative? I've looked everywhere for a solution, though, I can't seem to find one. If there is no solution, then how do websites such as: http://csgolounge.com/ and http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/ retrieve all their items?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this to retrieve the data from steam market.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=1&currency=3&language=english&format=json

Then modifying the link to get the weapon, skin and exterior I want. There is also this link that can be modified.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29

This I found from this thread.

[Get steam item prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513891/get-steam-item-prices)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this 
`https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v2/?key=<Steam key>&language=ru`