# Java Buy Items from Steam Community Market

Tags: java, steam

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to buy items off of the Steam Community Market through Java.  I'm assuming that I will also need help authenticating the purchase with steam login information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I got;

**Item Price**
https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=753&currency=21&market_hash_name=286570-ToroRosso%Card

**Purchase**
https://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder/

```
POST;
sessionid: ****
currency: 21
appid: 753
market_hash_name: 286570-ToroRosso Card
price_total: 4
quantity: 1
```

**Purchase listining**
https://steamcommunity.com/market/buylisting/*listiningID*

```
POST;
sessionid: ****
currency: 21
subtotal: 452
fee: 67
total: 519
quantity: 1
billing_state: ""
save_my_address: 0
```

So if you can get a session id and fill in the rest your sorted :p sorry it took 5 years xD

Comment: This will give 400 BAD request.

Comment: This is 2 years old... You can use chrome to listen to the api requests and work it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API the market, but some people are screen scraping the HTML or getting the JSON

[Get the price of an item on Steam Community Market with PHP and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055673/get-the-price-of-an-item-on-steam-community-market-with-php-and-regex)

[Get steam item prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513891/get-steam-item-prices)

You can do this in Java with a http client as well.

Comment: I've already gotten the price of the item, I just can't find a good source to find out how to buy the item automatically.  Let's say I already have all the details, I just need to buy the item.

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: I'm not using an HTTP Client.  I'm getting JSON from the Steam market, and getting the values I need.

Comment: Since there isn't a published API, you have 2 choices 1. Use a robot http client to synthetically push the buttons by ID like selenium does or 2. make a purchase and watch the network calls to discover APIs... I'm not confident in 2 due to security