# Steam API decode URL json

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

I am trying to make a "echo" prices for different objects I have got in an array that contains weapons:

I have read lots about how to get prices through through Steammarket through Steamapi:

(none of these sources did fit my requirements)
Sources:
[Get steam item prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513891/get-steam-item-prices)
[How get a response of multiple price items on the market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270881/how-get-a-response-of-multiple-price-items-on-the-market)
[Get the price of an item on Steam Community Market with PHP and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055673/get-the-price-of-an-item-on-steam-community-market-with-php-and-regex)

I found finally a code snippet that works flawless

FILE marketprices.php

```
<?php

     $items = array("Exalted Manifold Paradox","Kinetic Gem","Mercurial's Call");
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&market_hash_name=".rawurlencode($item)), true);
            if($json["success"] == true OR !empty($json))
            {
                echo $item."'s lowest price is ".$json["lowest_price"]."";
            }
            elseif($json["success"] == false OR empty($json))
            {
                echo "Could not get data for ".$item;
            }
        }
```

output>

```
Exalted Manifold Paradox's lowest price is $28.49Kinetic Gem's lowest price is $50.00Mercurial's Call's lowest price is $0.16
```

Source:http://gamebanana.com/tuts/11942

```
When I am trying to implent this snippet to my code I get error in my result:

I have created an array that contains different weapons:
<?
    foreach($S_W as $item) // Steam weapon
    {
    echo $item;
    }

?>
```

output>

```
AWP | Worm God (Factory New)
FAMAS | Cyanospatter (Field-Tested)
G3SG1 | Green Apple (Factory New)
G3SG1 | Polar Camo (Field-Tested)
Glock-18 | Death Rattle (Field-Tested)
M249 | Gator Mesh (Field-Tested)
MAC-10 | Heat (Field-Tested)
```

This is good so far..

I get error in the result
Here is my code below:

```
foreach($S_W as $item)
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&market_hash_name=".rawurlencode($item)), true);
    if($json["success"] == true OR !empty($json))
    {
        echo $item."'s lowest price is ".$json["lowest_price"]."";
    }
    elseif($json["success"] == false OR empty($json))
    {
        echo "Could not get data for ".$item;
    }
}
```

I receive following result:
[image]

I see a part of the error..
in the call in the end of the URL the code adds:`&lt;/br&gt;`

Could someone help me with a solution?

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: Are the snippets of code above from `MarketPrices.php` and do they show the offending lines?

Comment: @DanielElmnas: The decoded value of `&lt;/br&gt;` is `</br>`. That means the value has a single line break. Try the PHP's `strip_tags()` first.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail I am a newbie to PHP. Could you provide me with a snippet?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @DanielElmnas: also, you have a `&amp;` in the URL that you should replace. And delete the answer you posted as it is not an answer. You should update your question instead.

Comment: So the following result of the URL,
should look like the example below:


http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570/market_hash_name=AWP%20|%20Worm%20God%20(Factory%20New)

If I paste that in the browser I still get null

thank you in advance

Comment: @DanielElmnas: change `570/market_hash_name` to `570&market_hash_name`. It gets you some json. I am not familiar with how steam API works, though.

Comment: I still get null:

http://pastebin.com/7e4vVVbf

Answer (score -1):

Priceoverview 'API' endpoint is rate-limited by Steam, and was even further rate-limited by Valve very recently. You are getting 429 HTTP Status code, which stands for 'Too many requests', you are sending requests to their site way too often.

Comment: How do other people solve to create an array from the pricelist? 

Thank you in advance

Comment: @DanielElmnas one way would be to send requests under x amount per minute, I believe it may have been something like 20 requests/minute.

Comment: If I should send x requests per min how should you make it then? 
Could you help me with an example if it is not to hard.

by using the method I am using. Is this the easiest way to make this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Just noticed that you are sending incorrect appID for the CS:GO items, 570 is for Dota 2, 730 is for CS:GO.