# Method to get Steam Community Market prices in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup, steam

I'm using JSoup in a Java program to get the prices of CS:GO items on the Steam Community Market, but I'm having trouble finding a source in HTML for it.

In order for it to work, the weapons must be sorted by price (like [this](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p1_price_asc)) but in HTML form so I can parse the corresponding weapon to a given price if it meets a certain criteria.

Is there an API for this so I won't have to go scraping the HTML off a weirdly formatted page? Or can someone help me with my current method?

Comment: You should post an example of your current method, indicating exactly where it is not doing what you want it to (and also what it is expected to do). Also, bear in mind that whenever you scrape a site, the site-owner may at any time change the format, and it may stop working a few hours or days later

Comment: There is also a relevant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055673/get-the-price-of-an-item-on-steam-community-market-with-php-and-regex