# Using XML spreadSheet to get the price of an item

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, steam

I want to get the price of an item which is market in steam. I tried to use this formula but it is not working it tells me that the value is too big. and I did not know what to do. I want to get the price of an item which is on market on steam.

> Blockquote =VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Clutch%20Case", "//script[2]")),".*]]"), "[0-9]+.[0-9]+"))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the prices in the Steam page are generated by Javascript and `IMPORTXML` cannot retrieve dynamically generated data. It seems that you're trying to get around this by importing a `<script>` section, but this will not execute the script, you're just grabbing a bunch of code.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665733), Steam has some endpoints that you can use to get market data. These return a simple JSON string with the item information. The endpoint looks like this:

`http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=[ID]&market_hash_name=[Item name]`

The `appid` is the game's ID, and the `market_hash_name` is the URL-encoded name of the item. Conveniently you can already find these in the URL that you are already using, `https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Clutch%20Case`. The game ID is `730` and the name is `Clutch%20Case`. So you can plug these in to the endpoint to get this URL:

`http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Clutch%20Case`

The endpoint's JSON looks like this:

```js
{
   "success":true,
   "lowest_price":"$0.30",
   "volume":"94,440",
   "median_price":"$0.31"
}
```

Since you only care about the median price, we can use a formula with `REGEXEXTRACT` to extract only that part:

Here's a sample pasting the URL in A1.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("", IMPORTDATA(A1)), "median_price:""(\$[0-9]+.[0-9]+)")`

[image]

**Edit:** As mentioned in the answer I linked, you can test the `currency` parameter in the URL with different numbers to get other currencies. In your case you can try `currency=2`for pounds (£). You'll also have to edit the `REGEXEXTRACT` to account for this change:

URL: `http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=2&appid=730&market_hash_name=Clutch%20Case`

Formula: `=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("", IMPORTDATA(A1)), "median_price:""(£[0-9]+.[0-9]+)")`

Comment: Thank you it works fine. Just is any chance to change to the £ instead of $. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, when I try to multiply the price I am getting this  Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But '$0.10' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: I edited my answer with a way to get the values in pounds. The `MULTIPLY` function coerces the text to numbers depending on your locale, so it should work after you change it to £, but you'll probably have to retype the function. For me it's the other way around, it works for $ but not for £.

Comment: I do have an error "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "median_price:"(£[0-9]+.[0-9]+)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "{"success":truelowest_price:"$0.10"volume:"39033"median_price:"$0.11"}"."

Comment: It doesn't look like you've changed the URL. You need to change it to `currency=2` so Steam returns the price in pounds.