# How to get text after ">" symbol except HTML tag

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace text like this: `> here is text` to `something`

But my regexp replace HTML tags too: `<div class="class">text</div>`

result is `<div class="class" something text </div something`

regexp: `\>(?=(.*?))`

I tried to except HTML tag with negative lookbehind: `(?<!.+\<)\>(?=(.*?))` but it doesn't work.

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: For example: `<div class="test">here is text</div> > need to parse it`

Result should be: `<div class="test">here is text</div> something need to parse it`

Comment: @qwerty how about http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/5 ?

Comment: Do you want to change the text in between the tags or outside? You're questions seems like you want to change the text between but this comment suggests the text outside of the tags (Also, there appears to be an extra `>` at the end??).

Comment: Use [`DOM`](http://php.net/dom)....

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/tP2cS6/1 Please, look it. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @qwerty Perhaps something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/10). It's not very robust, I just want to make sure I'm on the right track here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
/<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?<\/\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|>/gs
```

Replacement string:

```
something
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/6)

Comment: what about `<div class="test">>here is text`

Comment: @user3218114 how about this `<(\w+)\b.*?>(?:.*?<\/\1>)?(*SKIP)(*F)|>`? http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/8

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you so much, it's really difficult regexp. Could you tell me about SKIP?

Comment: @RandomSeed `>` present outside the div tag got replaced.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you need that `\b`? Wouldn't the `(\w+)` capture all the way up to the boundary anyways? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @qwerty `<(\w+)\b.*?>(?:.*?<\/\1>)?` Matches the whole tag. Following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail. And the regex after the `|` symbol would be matched from the remaining string. In our case it's `>`

Comment: I believe it still doesn't work with a real HTML document (e.g. http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/11) But you still have my +1 for this mind-twisting RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with a regex is [mission (almost) impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1446005). I would rather fully parse the HTML with the [built-in PHP features](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

At this point, after you have segregated tags and contents, it becomes trivial to apply the changes you need ([usage example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627553/1446005)) (possibly with a regex if you really want to :)

Comment: I do not need parse HTML with regexp. I need to replace text with `>` symbol to `something text`. But it should not replace HTML tag.

Comment: You do need to parse HTML to some extent, to differentiate tag ends (e.g. `<tag>`), attribute values (e.g. `<tag attr=">">`) and real text (e.g. `<tag> contents here > </tag>`.

Comment: Also notice that, formally speaking, the character `>` is forbidden inside a HTML document. It is supposed to be replaced by its HTML entity (`&gt;`). You may want to replace such entities too.