# How to extract or filter out information from HTML with PHP?

Tags: php, html, filter

I get an email with an html document every day with statistics from the day earlier. This HTML is hard to read for all users, so I want to extract information from this table "automaticly" with a php script. I will put the source code under here, where I just edit out sensitive information. The lines are "endless", so I just include a few lines so you can see the idea.

Just to give you an idea of what I want or need, is to bundle a lot of the information together, and make it "searchable" in php so I can create my own custom view of the information. If ex. there is 3 sellers that day, instead of 50 lines of wares, it would be 3 lines, where it says numbers of wares instead of each ware.

```
<html  dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><title>Outdata of rapport</title>                                                                                                                                      <style>table.list    { border-collapse: collapse; }</style>                                                                                                                                                                                                    </head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <!script!>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     <body bgcolor="#E8EAD8">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       <blockquote>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <p align=left><font size=+2><b> </b></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                <p align=left>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <font style="font-family:monospaced"> <table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black ><colgroup><colgroup>  <tbody><tr><td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0002003>Data statistic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0002030>Numbers</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tbody><tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0004003>Transfered&nbsp;posts&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0004030>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;140</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0005003>Defined&nbsp;sum lines</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0005030>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tbody></tbody></table> <table  class="list" border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 rules=groups borderColor=black ><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup><colgroup>  <tbody><tr><td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008003>&nbsp;Date&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008015>Group</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008026>Varegrp.betegn.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008047>Ware</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008056>Ware text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008097>Seller&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008106>Name&nbsp;seller&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008132>Fil.</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008137>Name&nbsp;on&nbsp;filial&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DB</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#5dcbfd ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0008179>NumPos</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tbody><tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010015>030001&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010026>Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010047>10038&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010056>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4G,&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010106>Seller&nbsp;Two&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010168>&nbsp;1.000,40&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0010179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011015>030001&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011026>Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011047>10038&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011056>&nbsp;&nbsp;4G,&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011106>Seller&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;480,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0011179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012015>030306&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012026>Protection&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012047>10793&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012056>&nbsp;Wallet&nbsp;Case&nbsp;&nbsp;for&nbsp;Galaxy&nbsp;S5&nbsp;bl</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012106>Seller&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;195,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0012179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013015>030306&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013026>Protection&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013047>10794&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013056>&nbsp;Slim&nbsp;Wallet&nbsp;Case&nbsp;Galaxy&nbsp;S5,&nbsp;Brown</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013106>Seller&nbsp;Two&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;190,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0013179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014015>030304&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014026>Charger&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014047>10865&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014056>&nbsp;TravelCharger&nbsp;Micro&nbsp;USB,&nbsp;Black&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014106>Seller&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;180,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0014179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015015>030306&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015026>Protection&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015047>11092&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015056>&nbsp;Slim&nbsp;Wallet&nbsp;Case&nbsp;f&nbsp;Xperia&nbsp;Z3&nbsp;Comp</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015106>Seller&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;250,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#d7ecf4 ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0015179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr>  <tr><td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016003>&nbsp;30.04.2015</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016015>030306&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016026>Protection&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016047>11099&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016056>&nbsp;Slim&nbsp;Wallet&nbsp;Case&nbsp;f&nbsp;Xperia&nbsp;Z3&nbsp;blac</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016097>99999999</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016106>Seller&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016132>0171</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016137>Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016168>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;170,20&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  <td style= background:#eef9ff ><font face="courier new" size="2"><nobr   id=l0016179>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;</nobr></font></td>  </tr><tbody></tbody></table>                                                                                                                                                                          </p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           </blockquote>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </html>
```

Comment: So you get an email from a external source that you cant edit yourself, and you want to re-format that email, then send to your users?

Comment: Yes I get an email that I cannot edit. But no, it will not be sendt forward. I will create a static webpage with stats view.

Comment: Im gussing you're trying to automatically fetch this email and make a view for you, then you need to look into IMAP with php and check for a pattern in that email that you can look for in the php the script. And when you have the code ready for fetching the email you need to setup a CRON job to check for this email every morning or so. Here's something that will get you started http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: As mentioned, you'd first have to get the email into the php script, using IMAP or some other process. Once there, use DOMDocument to parse the HTML, then extract the data from the appropriate HTML nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Document Object Model:](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Also check out this answer: [PHP Parse HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code)

Comment: That looks good, but is there a way for me to sort all the "TD" into the titles in the table? Looks like it will be hard to create a parser for all this information.