# PHP file() to foreach array and into img

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

I have been trying to convert to images the results from a list produced by file() an by file_get_contents and I have got this far but cant seem to be getting any where: Here's what I got:

```
<?php
$data = file('http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/');

foreach((array)$data as $whoisline){
echo '<img src="http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/'.$whoisline.'">';
}
?>
```

So far I can see the ending double quotes and the closing bracket and that's it.

Any Idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: $data is already going to be an array. there's no point in casting an array to an array. done any basic debugging, like checking what `var_dump($data)` shows?

Comment: is that your site? just use `glob()`

Comment: Yes its mine, I use it as an images server;

Comment: no need to scrape your own site via HTTP, just access the directory directly and use glob()

Comment: No, Im doing this from a remote server.

Comment: ah ok then, no glob option - carry on ;-)

Comment: @Dagon Why now a spider? That scared me :) 'Ol flower was much nicer.

Comment: you could add a simple index file (API) and serve the files to your script in friendlier manor. but not a big deal

Comment: @Rizier123 i photographed it in the office, i thought it matched my friendly personality

Comment: If i Use:

        $data = file_get_contents ('http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/');  

I can see the list of files... All I want is to grab them in put them in the src of an IMG... This is getting to tough.

Comment: the problem is you get html in the way, you need to parse that to get to the directory listing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help of [**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) you could just do the following.

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html("http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/");

// Find all images
foreach($html->find("a") as $element) {
    if (substr(strrchr($element->href,'.'),1) == "jpg") {
        echo '<img src="http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/'. $element->href .'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's that worked like magic... Love You man!!

Thank's to all of you for your comments, I will analyse every reply to learn more from you guys...

Answer (score 0):

The data returned in your example using `file_get_contents` is HTML, so in order to extract the images you'll have to [parse the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code).

I would recommend using [curl](http://php.net/curl) instead to fetch the HTML as [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) doesn't always allow fetching of remote URLs.

Another option is to use [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) to extract the image URLs and then you can loop through them as desired.

If the directory is local, then you could use [glob](http://php.net/glob) and then the data returned will be an array that you can loop through.

Comment: "The data returned in file_get_contents" is what eve the remote server wants it to me

Comment: Pardon? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: i mean it is in this case, i wasjsut saying its not as a rule.

Comment: Ah ok yes, sorry I had already edited my answer before seeing your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

ok my idea for what it is worth:

on the http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/ site add an index.php:

```
<?php
$files=array();
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
$files[]=$filename;
}
echo json_encode($files);
```

on the script on the other server

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/');

    foreach(json_decode($data) as $myImage){
    echo '<img src="http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/'.$myImage.'">';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I would have to do the same for the other 14 thousand folders, I don't thing it would work, thanks anyway :)

Comment: you have a defult listing via appache

Comment: to make the pure scrapeing approach a LOT esier: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions

Answer (score -1):

You need to look into glob.

```
foreach (glob("/galerias/notas/22925/*.{png,jpg,tiff}") as $filename) {

echo '<img src="http://cadenanoticias.com.mx/galerias/notas/22925/'.$filename.'">';

}
```

Comment: um No, it wont.. "    **Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem**