# Trouble getting the name of a product from a webpage

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I've written a script in php to scrape the `title` of a product located at the top right corner in a webpage. The `title` is visible as ***`Gucci`***.

when I execute my below script, it gives me an error `Notice: Trying to get property 'plaintext' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\runcode\testfile.php on line 16`.

How can I get only the name `Gucci` from that webpage?

[Link to the url](https://www.farfetch.com//bd/shopping/men/gucci-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneaker-item-12964878.aspx)

I've written so far:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$link = "https://www.farfetch.com//bd/shopping/men/gucci-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneaker-item-12964878.aspx"; 

function get_content($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0',));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        $itemTitle = $dom->find('#bannerComponents-Container [itemprop="name"]', 0)->plaintext;
        echo "{$itemTitle}";
    }
get_content($link);
?>
```

Btw, the selector I've used within the script is flawless.

To clear the confusion I've copied a chunk of html elements from the ***page source*** which neither generats dynamically nor javascript encrypted so I don't find any reason for curl not to be able to handle that:

```
<div class="cdb2b6" id="bannerComponents-Container">
    <p class="_41db0e _527bd9 eda00d" data-tstid="merchandiseTag">New Season</p>
    <div class="_1c3e57">
        <h1 class="_61cb2e" itemProp="brand" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/Brand">
            <a href="/bd/shopping/men/gucci/items.aspx" class="fd9e8e e484bf _4a941d f140b0" data-trk="pp_infobrd" data-tstid="cardInfo-title" itemProp="url" aria-label="Gucci">
                <span itemProp="name">Gucci</span>
            </a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Post script: It's very pathetic that I had to show a real life example from another language to make sure the name `Gucci` is not dynamically generated as few comments and an answer have already indicated that***

The following script is written in python (using `requests` module which can't handle dynamic content):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.farfetch.com//bd/shopping/men/gucci-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneaker-item-12964878.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one('#bannerComponents-Container [itemprop="name"]').text
    print(item)
```

Output It produces:

```
Gucci
```

Now, it's clear that the content I look for is static.

Please check out the below image to recognize the `title` which I've already marked by a pencil.

[image]

Comment: does `$itemTitle = $dom->find('#bannerComponents-Container [itemprop="name"]', 0);` return an object?

Comment: What is the structure of input HTML ? Please include that in the question.

Comment: Try `[itemProp=name]` (capital P for some reason)

Comment: Please check out the edit. I've added some materials to bring the clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between your successful Python script and your PHP script is the use of session. Your PHP script doesn't use cookies, and that triggers a differend response from the server.

We have two options:

1. Change the selector. As mentioned in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419353/7811673), the item is still on the html, but in a different tag. We could get it with this selector:

   ```
   'a[itemprop="brand"]'
   ```
2. Use cookies. We can get the same response as your Python script if we use `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` and a temporary file to write/read the cookies.

   ```
   function get_content($url) {
       $cookieFileh = tmpfile();
       $cookieFile=stream_get_meta_data($cookieFileh)['uri'];
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_exec($ch);
       $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       fclose($cookieFileh); // thanks to tmpfile(), this also deletes the cookie file.
       $dom = new simple_html_dom();
       $dom->load($htmlContent);
       $itemTitle = $dom->find('#bannerComponents-Container [itemprop="name"]', 0)->plaintext;
       echo "{$itemTitle}";
   }

   $link = "https://www.farfetch.com/bd/shopping/men/gucci-rhyton-web-print-leather-sneaker-item-12964878.aspx"; 
   get_content($link);
   //Gucci
   ```

   This script performs two requests; the first request writes the cookies to file, the second reads and uses them.

   In this case the server returns a compressed response, so I've used `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to unzip the contents.

   Since you use headers only to set a user-agent, it's best to use the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option.

   I've set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false because I haven't set a certificate, and `CURL` fails to use HTTPS. If you can communicate with HTTPS sites it's best not to use this option for security reasons. If not, you could set a certifcate with `CURLOPT_CAINFO`.

Comment: You have always been a life saver to me. Your solution never goes astray. Thanks a lot. I have two small questions: 1. Your solution did fetch the right answer along with this line `Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\runcode\testfile.php on line 5`. How can i shake off that error. 2. Is there any way i can get the `page source` or `html content` programmatically using `php` as we get in python using `res = requests.get(url) ; print(res.text)`?

Comment: That is not an error, it's a notice that informs us about the temporary file. You could suppress it wit `@`, eg: `$cookieFile = @tempnam("/cookies", "CURLCOOKIE");`. About your second question, you can just echo the response content, if that's what you mean, eg `echo $htmlContent;`.

Comment: Please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392966/trouble-getting-source-code-from-a-webpage) to see what I meant by getting source code or html content. I deleted that post but undeleted now for you. ***Btw, `echoing $htmlContent;` I can see that the script just opens that webpage like we open a webpage in a browser not the html stuff.*** You deserve the bounty. However, let's wait as long as it is alive.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. You're trying to print HTML code on an browser, right? The problem is that a web browser is designed to interpret HTML code, so you see only the text. Sorry, I can't help you with that. But let me search for an answer, and if I find anything useful I'll let you know.

Comment: I thought i was the only person having such issue. Thankssssssss a trillion for the clarity.

Comment: No, that's the normal behaviour. You can print the html code if you execute your script from the command line. If you're running a server and want to print html code on a web page try [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: No damn way. This is it. I have been seraching for this for the last couple of weeks. Please feel free to make this comment as an answer so that i can accept it in my linked post.

Comment: Sure, just give me some time, I'm a little busy at the moment. Or you can answer if you want, I'll definitely upvote a correct answer.

Comment: what happens if you don't have access to the /cookies folder? use tmpfile. it's not at all uncommon for PHP scripts to not have write access to any folder except a special temp folder (as returned by sys_get_temp_dir() - but tmpfile() will take care of locating the folder for you, and take care of cleaning up the file when the handle is closed / or the script terminates.)

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks for the suggestion and edit. You're right, I should have used `/tmp` or `%TEMP%`.  BTW what do you think about the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option? Is there anything better I can do (besides what I've mentioned in my answer) when running this script from terminal?

Comment: @t.m.adam actually you should neither use `/tmp` nor `%TEMP%`, you should use the return value of `sys_get_temp_dir()`, like `tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"cookiefile");` (or better yet, use tmpfile() )- as for CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , you can get a certificate bundle at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and use that with CURLOPT_CAINFO, and enable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Comment: @hanshenrik  Yes, I agree that it's best to use `sys_get_temp_dir()` which is more reliable, instead of hardcoding the path. About CURL, I'm aware of the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option (I've mentioned it in my answer), but I was hoping for a method that doesn't require a cerificate; however it's much better than disabling verification.

Comment: @ssnobody That wouldn't print the html tags on the page. But you could surround `htmlspecialchars` with pre tags, so it would preserve the original format.

Comment: Feel free to take a look at ***[this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593742/cant-modify-my-script-to-delimit-the-number-of-requests-while-scraping)*** in your spare time @t.m.adam.

Answer (score 3):

@t.m.adam already solved the problem, i just want to add that there's no good reason to use simple_html_dom today, seems unmaintained, development stopped in 2014, there's lots of unresolved bugreports, and most importantly, DOMDocument & DOMXPath can do just about everything simple_html_dom can, and is maintained, and is an integrated part of PHP, which means there's nothing to include/bundle with your script. parsing it with DOMDocument & DOMXPath would look like:

```
$htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($cookieFileh); // thanks to tmpfile(), this also deletes the cookie file.
$dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($htmlContent);
$xp=new DOMXPath($dom);
$itemTitle = $xp->query('//*[@id="bannerComponents-Container"]//*[@itemprop="name"]')->item(0)->textContent;
echo $itemTitle;
```

Comment: If I wish to use css selector instead of xpath complying with your above approach, how would that modified portion look like? Thanks for your invaluable input @hanshenrik.

Comment: @asmitu sorry, afaik there is nothing built-in to PHP that supports CSS - but if you're using Symfony, they have this [CSS-to-xpath converter](https://symfony.com/components/CssSelector), in which case you can run ```$converter = new Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelectorConverter();  $itemTitle = $xp->query($converter->toXPath('#bannerComponents-Container [itemprop="name"]'))->item(0)->textContent;```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector works in a browser indeed, but your selector is not present when you use curl to get the page source.

Try saving the curled page in terminal and you'll see that the page structure is different from what you see in the browser.

This is true for most modern websites because they use Javascript heavily and curl does not run javascript for you.

I saved the curl results into a file, the brand info looks like this:

`<a itemprop="brand" class="generic" data-tstid="Label_ItemBrand" href="/bd/shopping/men/gucci/items.aspx" dir="ltr">Gucci</a>`